# Load clob from "insert into" output file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

In the process of moving data from live to the dev system (completely isolated), I have been given a series of "insert into" files for the affected tables.

One of these tables contains a clob that houses stupidly massive sql queries, so the file contains stupidly massive amounts of text that cannot be inserted via the insert statement...

So, the question is, how can I import the data for this table?

Comment: What kind of file did you get? Is it a data pump dump or is it a kind of CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Since they are sql insert files you can only import them using the sqlplus utility. I'd say a dumpfile in this case is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ask for a DataPump export file of this particular table. Here's how you you do it:

```
create or replace directory DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/path to dump file/';

expdp userid=SYSTEM/PW@\"localhost:1521:[source database name]\" full=n include=tableowner.tablename directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=tablename%U.dmp logfile=tablename_expdp.log
```

Then import:

```
create or replace directory DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/path to dump file/';

impdp userid=SYSTEM/PW@\"localhost:1521:[target database name]\" FULL=Y DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR CONTENT=ALL LOGFILE=tablename_impdp.log DUMPFILE=tablename%U.dmp
```

If the person doesn't have the system password, use the schema owner instead, or connect using os authentication: `expdp userid=\"/ as sysdba\" ...`